# R plot using tikzDevice in LaTeX document with knitr

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex, knitr, tikz

I am having a problem making ggplot2, tikzDevice, and knitr working together. I am working with RStudio, and trying to include some R graphics in a Latex document. 
I used a very simple example:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure} 
<<fig1,eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE,dev='tikz'>>= 
library(ggplot2)
library(tikzDevice)
qplot(displ, hwy, data = mpg, colour = factor(cyl)) 
@ 
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

But no pdf is output, and I get the following error message:

```
Error in getMetricsFromLatex(TeXMetrics) : 
TeX was unable to calculate metrics for the following string
or character:

    hwy

Common reasons for failure include:
  * The string contains a character which is special to LaTeX unless
    escaped properly, such as % or $.
  * The string makes use of LaTeX commands provided by a package and
    the tikzDevice was not told to load the package.

The contents of the LaTeX log of the aborted run have been printed above,
it may contain additional details as to why the metric calculation failed.
Calls: knit ... widthDetails.text -> grid.Call -> <Anonymous> -> getMetricsFromLatex

Execution halted
```

This problem has been treated [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-figures-td4651714.html), but the solution proposed does not work for me. Any idea?

Comment: I ran your code exactly and get the desired output: https://github.com/trinker/temp/blob/master/temp.pdf?raw=true.  Here is the repo that I will delete later: https://github.com/trinker/temp/

Comment: Is everything ok when using any other device? May help to locate the problem.

Comment: If you are using RStudio, this might be a problem of encoding. Try to look at your code in some other editor, maybe special characters turn up, or switch to some other encoding in RStudio.

Comment: Which other editor or device would you recommend me to use, instead of RStudio?

Comment: I believe encoding is irrelevant here. It is often an indication of missing LaTeX packages. At least you need to install the `pgf` and `preview` packages. Please include `library(knitr); library(tikzDevice); sessionInfo()` so we do not have to guess your OS in case you have further questions.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem. What I had to to was, first, to run pdflatex with a simple r code (like '1+1') and the commands to download the latex packages recommanded by Yihui; and then, run it another time with my code above.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a clash with another package you haven't included in your simple example? For me, I was getting this error message because of some clash between package `xcolor` and `tikz`. I was calling `xcolor` before `Tikz`, no problem, but as soon as I set `dev="tikz"` in the chunk options I got the same error as you.  As soon as I removed `\usepackage{xcolor}` everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

I added in the R code

```
options(tikzMetricPackages = c("\\usepackage[utf8{inputenc}",
    "\\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}", "\\usetikzlibrary{calc}", "\\usepackage{amssymb}"))
```

[source](http://freakonometrics.hypotheses.org/6290)