# knitr plots: Points (geom_point(), pch=20, pch=19...) not showing

Tags: r, plot, windows-7, knitr, miktex

I'm a bit troubled with some behaviour of knitr. The working example should show 4 plots, all showing the same data using 2 different plot-methods.

Preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
```

The first two plots are made using the plot command of R-base:

```
<<one.one,fig.width=4,fig.height=3,fil.align='center',fig.show='asis'>>=
par(mar=c(4,4,1,1),mgp=c(2,1,0),cex=0.8)
plot(cars,pch=20,col='darkgray')
@
<<one.two,fig.width=4,fig.height=3,fil.align='center',fig.show='asis'>>=
par(mar=c(4,4,1,1),mgp=c(2,1,0),cex=0.8)
plot(cars,pch=18,col='darkgray')
@
```

The outputs are then given by (deleted):

For the same plot with ggplot2 the code examples are:

```
<<two.one,fig.width=4,fig.height=3,fil.align='center',fig.show='asis'>>=
library(ggplot2)
test1<-ggplot(cars,aes(x=speed,y=dist))
test2<-test1+geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE,color='red',data=fit)
test3<-test2+
ggtitle("") +
geom_point(size=1,colour='red')
test3
@
<<two.two,fig.width=4,fig.height=3,fil.align='center',fig.show='asis'>>=
test1<-ggplot(cars,aes(x=speed,y=dist))
test2<-test1+geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE,color='red',data=fit)
test3<-test2+
ggtitle("") +
geom_point(size=1,colour='red',shape=3)
test3
@
```

And the outputs are (deleted):

Even using tikzDevice doesn't solve the issue for me. The problem exists for me since Nov. last year, at least as far as I can remember. I tried solving by reading Yihui Xie's book, used examples from his website, but failed.

So: Has anyone seen the same problem and has come up with a solution to it? Even a hint pointing in a certain direction might help.

My System:

Win 7, MikTeX2.9 (packages updated on 15.01.2016), TeXstudio 2.10.6, R3.2.2 (packages updated on 15.01.2016).

---

Edit:

As asked by CL, I updated R and the packages right along, too. Below you find my MWE. The problem of not-showing data points when using
    pch=20 ; pch=19, geom_point()
is persistent as long as I don't choose a graphics device explictly. When using **tikzDevice** and saving the plots to *.tex, the data points show. They also show when putting 
    dev='tikz'
into the chunk options. Other graphic devices seem to work as well.

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
this chunk options:

fig.width=4,fig.height=3,fig.align='center',fig.show='asis'
\end{verbatim}

<<one.one,fig.width=4,fig.height=3,fig.align='center',fig.show='asis'>>=
library(knitr)

par(mar=c(4,4,1,1),mgp=c(2,1,0),cex=0.8)
plot(cars,pch=20,col='darkgray')
fit<-lm(dist~speed, data=cars)
abline(fit,lwd=1,col='red')

par(mar=c(4,4,1,1),mgp=c(2,1,0),cex=0.8)
plot(cars,pch=18,col='darkgray')
fit<-lm(dist~speed, data=cars)
abline(fit,lwd=1,col='red')

library(ggplot2)
test1<-ggplot(cars,aes(x=speed,y=dist))
test2<-test1+geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE,color='red',data=fit)
test3<-test2+
ggtitle("") +
geom_point(size=1,colour='red')
test3

test1<-ggplot(cars,aes(x=speed,y=dist))
test2<-test1+geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE,color='red',data=fit)
test3<-test2+
ggtitle("") +
geom_point(size=1,colour='red',shape=3)
test3
@

\begin{verbatim}
next chunk options:

three.one,fig.width=4,fig.height=3,fig.align='center',fig.show='asis'
\end{verbatim}

<<three.one,fig.width=4,fig.height=3,fig.align='center',fig.show='asis'>>=
require(tikzDevice)
tikz("three.one.tex",width=4.2,height=3)
plot(cars,pch=20,col='darkgray')
fit<-lm(dist~speed, data=cars)
abline(fit,lwd=1,col='red')
dev.off()

tikz("four.one.tex",width=4.2,height=3)
test1<-ggplot(cars,aes(x=speed,y=dist))
test2<-test1+geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE,color='red',data=fit)
test3<-test2+
ggtitle("") +
geom_point(size=1,colour='red')
test3
dev.off()
@
\input{three.one.tex}

\input{four.one.tex}

\begin{verbatim}
next chunk options:

five.one,fig.width=4,fig.height=3,fig.align='center',fig.show='asis, dev='tikz'
\end{verbatim}

<<five.one,fig.width=4,fig.height=3,fig.align='center',fig.show='asis',dev='tikz'>>=
plot(cars,pch=20,col='darkgray')
abline(fit,lwd=1,col='red')

test1<-ggplot(cars,aes(x=speed,y=dist))
test2<-test1+geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE,color='red',data=fit)
test3<-test2+
ggtitle("") +
geom_point(size=1,colour='red')
test3
@

\begin{verbatim}
next chunk options:

five.one,fig.width=4,fig.height=3,fig.align='center',fig.show='asis, dev=c('png','pdf')
\end{verbatim}

<<seven.one,fig.width=4,fig.height=3,fig.align='center',fig.show='asis',dev=c('png', 'pdf')>>=
plot(cars,pch=20,col='darkgray')
abline(fit,lwd=1,col='red')

test1<-ggplot(cars,aes(x=speed,y=dist))
test2<-test1+geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE,color='red',data=fit)
test3<-test2+
ggtitle("") +
geom_point(size=1,colour='red')
test3
@
\end{document}
```

If that issue is not reproducible, I will make my peace with it and ignore it. But if it's reproducible, I'm curious what a solution might look like.

Along with the tests, I came up with another issue and I found that problem to be stated by at least one other TeX-user, too: Knitr and the LaTeX package xcolor don't seem to be the best of all friends.

Thank's again.

[knitr vs. xcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542556/r-plot-using-tikzdevice-in-latex-document-with-knitr)

Comment: Is it a simple typo where you have `fil.align` that should be `fig.align`?

Comment: Also, what's your *complete* document? Its not just that one line "preamble" is it? Because you need a full LaTeX `document` environment... Do you get any text output? Have you checked the logs and messages?

Comment: ad1) It's a typo here. Thank you.

Comment: ad2) As I wanted to give a minimum working example with no other packages interfering, I deleted anything not necessary. The complete outputs above are build from something like:

`\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
<<>>=
@
\end{document}`

I get a text-output, as well as for annotations in the plots as for text around the plots, formulas, tables, no problems there.

Warnings: _In (if (out_format(c("latex", "sweave", "listings"))) sanitize_fn else paste0)(path, : dots in figure paths replaced with _ ("figure/one_one")_ .

Comment: OK. Whatever has changed in the document or the packages or where-ever: Using **tikzDevice** solves the problem for now. However, as the figure is not include by **knitr** anymore but with  `\include{*.tex}` it's only a work-around, not a solution. I don't know whether to close this or to keep it open.

Comment: 1) Please update to the current R version (3.2.3) and *then* update packages. 2) I don't get the problem; the code presented definitely doesn't produce the plots shown (no straight line in code for first 2 plots) and the `ggplot` part isn't reproducible without the object `fit`. A minimal example should be self-contained: Minimal, but containing *all relevant steps* to reproduce the problem. So what exactly is the problem? The missing points in plot 1 and plot 3? 3) What does the comment on `tikzDevice` mean? Using `dev = "tikz"` still "includes the figure by knitr".

Comment: ad 1) Done.
ad 2) Done.
ad 3) Point was, only an explicit call of a graphics device makes the data points show when a no-call of a device makes no issue of showing other symbols than points in a scatter plot. The communication problem might be due to my english.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce the problem. On my system, all plots look just fine (no missing points). I suppose this could have something to do with the fonts on your system, but that's just guessing. (Don't worry about your English, it's not hard to understand you. Many people here are not native english speakers - (obviously) including me.)

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put in testing on your system. Thought that much because, if that issue was reproducible quite often, the author of **knitr** would have done something about it. Anyway, I'm going to ignore it.